# 日本語に違和感: アクティビティの「回のリビジョン」

Tags: 討議, バグ, 完了, 翻訳

ユーザー画面のアクティビティにある「回のリビジョン」ですが、不自然なので直した方が良い様に思います。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

個人的には日本語にせず「リビジョン」のままがいいなと思うのですが、

日本語にするならば、内容としては編集履歴が一覧表示されているようなので「編集履歴」とか、  
「編集」「修正」「改訂」といったrevisionの単語の意味でもいいかもしれません。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

英語版では「Revisions」ですが、何回編集したということを示すため、「編集」がいいと思います。